# How to make <div> x times bigger? But not lineary bigger, it has to stop

Tags: html, css, math, zooming

Ok, so I have this tag cloud in the sidebar of my blog:

```
<div id="tags" class="widget clearfix">

    <h4 class="highlight-me">Nuage de tags</h4>
    <div class="tagcloud ">
        {% for tag, occurence in tags %}
            <a style="zoom: {{ 1 + (occurence - 1) * 0.25  }}" href="#">{{ tag }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

</div>
```

`tags` is in array with the *labels* of tags as **key** and the *number of appearance* among all the blog articles as **values**. The goal is the more the tag appears, the bigger it is displayed (with the `zoom:` CSS inline declaration).

The formula I came up with is therefore : `1 + (x - 1) * 0.25`. In that way, unique tags have a `1` zoom, tags that are twice are `1.25`, three times tags are `1.50`, `1.75`, etc. This formula adds `0.25` by appearance to the value of the CSS zoom declaration **in a linear way**.

This is acceptable as long as no tags are used in more than 3 or 4 articles. But this won't be acceptable anymore when I'll have 50+ articles in the blog. I don't want the most popular tags to take too much space. For exemple, have a tag displayed with a `6.75` zoom which will be the case if used in 23 articles is not acceptable.

What would be the formula to make the zoom growth not linear anymore?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use font size?

Comment: @G-Cyr > the problem is not which CSS to use, but what number to calculate in order that the value grows not linearily. I don't want most popular tags to take too much space.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=Zoom maybe not the best for Firefox users ;)  a max value could be used. Adding a few rem is à commun way and works everywhere.

Comment: @G-Cyr > I'm aware of the uncompatibility of `zoom` CSS declaration, I was going for something else as soon as I got sorted this coefficient thing. What are you suggesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are "allowed" to do or not.

but mathematically speeking [this formula](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNR8pVDLnL3tXn72eV2eryI_74Jkyg%3A1577373771684&ei=S9AEXr2xKYGVlwSbpKL4Dw&q=%3Darctan%28x%2F4%29%20%2B%201&oq=%3Darctan%28x%2F4%29%20%2B%201&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i8i30l3j0i8i10i30j0i8i30l4j0i333l2.13795.13916..13990...0.2..0.87.87.1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71._1g7dW7Elv4&ved=0ahUKEwj9gtuaz9PmAhWByoUKHRuSCP8Q4dUDCAs&uact=5) seems to do the exact value you want : `y = arctan(x/4) + 1`
Always rising and increasingly less rising, bounded toward infinite, etc...

Be also aware that your problem (considering your constraints) might not have a solution if do not have access to decent math functions.

Comment: I'm using PHP (Symfony + Twig) and I managed to use the `tan()` PHP function to set up what you adviced. Many thanks!